# Mithril ajax sending empty inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, mithril.js

I'm trying to send a POST request through ajax and Mithril.js using CodeIgniter. But for some reason the input always is empty. I have tried with a regular ajax post request and that works fine, but Mithril doesn't.

```
       m.request({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/index.php/login",
            data: {
                username: $("#login-username").val(), 
                password: $("#login-password").val()
            }
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result)
        })
```

And the php

```
public function login()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');

        die($username);
    }
```

It always prints "null" in console. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

```
 <form class="uk-form-stacked uk-margin-remove" id="login-form" method="post" action="index.php/login">
            <fieldset class="uk-fieldset">
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-inline uk-width-1-1">
                        <span class="uk-form-icon" uk-icon="icon: user"></span>
                        <input class="uk-input" id="login-username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <div class="uk-inline uk-width-1-1">
                        <span class="uk-form-icon" uk-icon="icon: lock"></span>
                        <input class="uk-input" id="login-password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="uk-margin" style="margin-top:10px">
                    <label ><input class="uk-checkbox" type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-width-1-1" value="Login">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Routes:

```
$route['login']['post'] = 'Users/login';
```

Comment: does the http request return 200 in your developer tools of the browser?

Comment: @messerbill Yes it returns status 200.

Comment: What do the Request Headers look like in developer tools? You should be able to see if the fields were or were not posted.

Comment: @DFriend the Request Payloads can detect the inputs specified.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` in login. If it doesn't show the same info as the Request Payloads then some other code has run before `login()` that has removed/modified the posted fields/values.

Comment: @DFriend Thanks for the tip. I tried this and the $_POST is empty.

Comment: Look for a "hook" that intercepts inputs before the controller get it.

Comment: @DFriend I'm relatively new to CI 3. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Read about CI's "hooks" [HERE](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)

Comment: Code in `User::__construct()` or a class that `User` extends could be other places that have the opportunity to change `$_POST` before it gets to `login()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will send a JSON body to the server, not a form submission. I'm guessing your PHP code expects the data to be formatted like a `<form>` would send it, so for that you'd want to use a `FormData` instance.

```
var data = new FormData();

data.append("username", document.querySelector("#username").value);
data.append("password", document.querySelector("#password").value);

m.request({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
        data: data
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    })
```

I also set up a JsBin where you can see this working & poke at it.

https://jsbin.com/gififo/2/

Comment: Thanks! So happy to finally have a solution for this problem!

Answer (score 0):

try print the data to be able to see it i the console .

```
public function login()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        echo $username;
    }
```

Comment: It still returns null.

Comment: Added to the OP.

Comment: @P.Nick so in your url you should provide a valid url

Comment: @P.Nick it seems that it is not avalid url. where is the controller name  url: "http://localhost/index.php/(controller name)/login",

Comment: What do you mean it's not a valid url? I have tried the same url with standard jquery ajax and it returns the username to the console. Have also tried all kinds of URLs I can think of for mithril but everything returns null.

Comment: @P.Nick what is the controller name or file name you call the login function from?

Comment: It's called ``Users.php`` - and to clarify, if I do ``die("1")`` it prints ``1`` into the console. It's simply just the input thats empty, nothing wrong with the url...

Comment: Is the file `Users.php` define a class named Users the extends CI_Controller? What is the route setting that allows the url ` `http://localhost/index.php/login` to find Users.php ?

Comment: @DFriend yes the Users class extends CI_Controller. I have also updated op with my route.

Comment: That's the kind of info you should include in your question otherwise people accuse you of using invalid urls. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have define a route (in app/config/route.php) but, actually you are pointing to the default controller.

If you are trying to send your request to, for exemple, the `login` method of the `users` controller, your request path should be `http://localhost/index.php/users/login`

I also recommand you to use the `base_url` function instead of a simple string, which is far more easier when you deploy your app on the real server.

So, I propose to change this line

```
url: "http://localhost/index.php/users/login",
```

By

```
url: <?= json_encode(base_url("/users/login")) ?>,
```

For this function work, you should have load the `URI` helper, in your controller `__construct` or directly in your current method :

```
$this->load->helper('URI');
```

Comment: I have updated op with my routes.php now, tell me if they're wrong. Also I run this script in a separate .js file so I can't access PHP functions in it.